How to merge the data of Apache IoTDB Version 1.3 cluster of the two servers?
How can I merge the data of the two Apache IoTDB cluster in version 1.3? I remember in the previous versions, the synchronizing should be executed every 3 hours, is the new version still executed in this way by default? Can real-time synchronization be performed by modifying the configuration, and what configuration should I change?

The synchronization of the open-source version of Apache IoTDB is based on TsFiles. Historical files will be sync directly, and new files are sync once they are generated. The file generation time depends one the memory size and writing speed, ranging from a few minutes to a few hours. If you want to manually trigger file generation, you can execute the flush command, but it is not recommended to execute it too frequently(in seconds or minutes), as it may affect read and write performance of IoTDB.
